# Actor selection

Tags: scala, akka

Why when I select an absolute path with ActorContext it doesn't works (the actor isn't correctly selected and doesn't receive the HelloResponse message) ?

```
//From Actor2:
//This doesn't work (Message never received)
context.actorSelection("/user/actor1") ! HelloResponse("hello back1")
//This works (actor 1 receives the message)
context.system.actorSelection("/user/actor1") ! HelloResponse("hello back2")
```

I'm newbie to Scala/Akka but [reading documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actorselection-scala) it seems that should work.

Comment: Please provide the following: 1) Scala/Akka versions 2) Code that shows how `actor1` is created 3) What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it compile? Does it throw an exception at runtime? Doesn't `actor1` receive the `HelloResponse("hello back1")` message? What does the error message say?

Comment: I added an explanation about what doesn't work mean, thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, thanks for asking: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/ddEDvgVAKr3QrUeJe5aVNr/tickets/3276

Answer (score 2):

When you use `context.actorSelection` inside of an actor, what you are saying is find an actor under this current actors control (started by/supervised by).  Since actor1 was probably not started by actor2 (or is not supervised by actor2), then it won't resolve to anything.  If actor1 was actually owned/started by actor2 then you could probably do `context.actorSelection("/actor1")` to get that child actor of actor2.  The reason `context.system.actorSelection` works is because you are going all the way "up" to `system` first before starting your search and fully qualifying the path to the actor.  System "owns" actor1 if you started it up as `system.actorOf`, so using that path will allow you to get to it starting from `system`.

A little code to show what I mean:

```
class Actor1 extends Actor{
  override def preStart = {
    context.actorOf(Props[Actor2], "actor2")
  }
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}

class Actor2 extends Actor{
  override def preStart = {println("my path is: " + context.self.path)}
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}

object FutureTesting {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sys = ActorSystem("test")
    implicit val ec = sys.dispatcher

    //Starting an Actor2 from system
    sys.actorOf(Props[Actor2], "actor2")

    //Starting an Actor1 from system which in turn starts an Actor2
    sys.actorOf(Props[Actor1], "actor1")
  }
}
```

When you run this example, you will see:

```
my path is: akka://test/user/actor1/actor2
my path is: akka://test/user/actor2
```

So you can see that I have 2 instances of `Actor2` running in my system; one spawned directly from `sys` tied to `/user/actor2` as it's lookup path and one started from an instance of `Actor1` tied to `/user/actor1/actor2` for its path.

The actor system is hierarchical and this example shows that.  The `ActorSystem` itself is the root to everything.  Selecting actors is then similar to XPath in that the context that you are issuing the select from matters.

Answer (score 1):

From `actor2` you will need to use

```
context.actorSelection("/actor1")
```

I agree it is not intuitive given the metaphor is a filesystem and when using a filesystem a leading `/` is an absolute path meaning start at the root.  Also it is inconsistent with `actorFor` because

```
context.actorFor("/user/actor1")
```

returns the top level `Actor1` (see [Absolute and Relative Paths](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/general/addressing.html#Absolute_vs__Relative_Paths))

EDIT - this was a bug that was fixed in Akka 2.1.4 (see Roland's answer).  From 2.1.4 onwards you can use `context.actorSelection("/user/actor1")`.

Comment: The first snippet: context.actorSelection("/actor1") will not work either. If the forward slash exists, ActorSelection will resolve starting at the root guardian as Roland mentions.

Comment: It was working but was a bug and has since been fixed.

Comment: Just tested with Akka 2.3-M2, and context.actorSelection("/actor1") doesn't work. The ActorSelection will start resolving at the root guardian.

Comment: It was fixed in 2.1.4